# How to offset spring kafka to next in error handler?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring data 1.5.8 and manual ack mode of kafka. There is only a simple ErrorHandler interface, the handle method has parameter exception and consumerRecord, but how can I set the offset to next if exception threw when json can not be deserialized? I need omit the message or else the consumer will stuck there

spring data 2.0 introduce ConsumerAwareErrorHandler, the only way is update spring version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to upgrade. The current version is 2 4.0 or 2.3.4.